# Different versions of files in different hours

Tags: bash, command-line, cron, anacron

On my laptop, I have three files: `file`, `file-morning` and `file-afternoon`. I want `file` to be a copy of `file-morning` before 12AM and a copy of `file-afternoon` after 12AM. Ideally, I would like to be able to add another time intervals easily. This all should work no matter whether the laptop slept, was turned off or hibernated. In given times, I just want to find the correct version of the file.

I do not think that either `cron` or `anacron` can schedule such job, can they? I mean, I do not see a solution which would not require me to write a script checking the time itself.

My use case are rules for url blocking for a transparent proxy server to prevent myself from browsing certain websites compulsively and learn that there are times for that :-D

Comment: crontab has a `@reboot` that can run a command on each boot up.

Comment: `man 5 crontab` depending on which variant for cron you're using imo.

Comment: Do you suggest to have one cron task at 12AM which switches the files if the computer is on and another cron task at reboot which checks what time it is and switches the files accordingly in case the computer was off at 12AM? Will it work with hibernation and sleep? The idea is to always find the correct file at given time, no matter what has happened with the computer inbetween.

Comment: I would advise making "file" a soft link to whichever specific file you wish to be current. Cron will certainly manage the time-of-day and reboot transitions: I'm not sure how you would detect exits from sleep and hibernate states. You could also schedule a check in cron every 5 minutes (maybe) as it's a trivial check, and if you can tolerate that period of uncertainty in that circumstance. There is a directory `/etc/apm/resume.d` in Linux Mint which suggests you can configure systemd to trigger a script from suspend and hibernate.